# Grouping by data based on month-year via expression in ssrs2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a matrix in ssrs 2008 like

```
Date                    Data
<<Expr>>                [Fields!Data.Value]
```

where expr is:

`MonthName(Month(Fields!StartPeriod.Value), True) + " " + CStr(Year(Fields!StartPeriod.Value)) + " - " + MonthName(Month(Fields!EndPeriod.Value), True) + " " + CStr(Year(Fields!EndPeriod.Value))`

In this case, I have the output like:

```
Date                    Data
March2014-April,2014    10
March2014-April,2014    20 
March2014-April,2014    30
March2014-April,2014    40
April,2014-May2014      ...
April,2014-May2014
April,2014-May2014
April,2014-May2014
May2014-June2014
May2014-June2014
May2014-June2014
May2014-June2014
June2014-July2014
June2014-July2014
June2014-July2014
June2014-July2014
```

However, I want it grouped like:

```
Date                    Data
March2014-April,2014    100
April,2014-May2014      ...
May2014-June2014        ...
June2014-July2014       ...
```

I tried to add a groupby endtime to the related row grout but it is not working since endtime is coming from the query weekly (4 days for 4 weeks in a month, so 4 row for one month). When I write the same expression in the group by filter, it is not working as well. I couldnt find how to provide this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a group using the expression for Date, once the group exists you can aggregate your Data field.

Go to `Rows Groups` and create a `Parent Group`. Use the expression you have to produce Date.

[image]

To calculate the sum of Data use:

```
=Sum(Fields!Data.Value)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to add a Calculated Field to your dataset. Use the existing expression you mentioned. Then you can simply group on that new column.